# remove content from iframe by jquery or prototype.js?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I want to open a url in ifrmae on click of a link.I am using following code.

```
//Prototype Js code 
Event.observe(window,'load',function(){ 
    $('button').observe('click', function()  {
         $('login-slide').update('<iframe src="domian" />');    
         $('test').remove();
 );
```

But I want to show only some part of the IFRAME.
I know, by remove function, I can delete the content. But it is not working in iframe.
Please guide me how can I do this?

Comment: I've tried to format your code, but I'm not entirely sure how it's meant to be so you should probably fix that first. You have not closed the click event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the the functions properly. And you will be able to modify IFRAME content only if it is on the same domain.

```
Event.observe(window,'load',function(){ 
    $('button').observe('click', function()  {
         $('login-slide').update('<iframe src="domian" />');    
         $('test').remove();
    });
});
```